# Twitch API and displaying online status

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I am currently trying to add online indicators for lists of streams but am unaware as to how to do that using query lists etc.

Comment: Could you please add more details here ? Like what is the use case, What have you tried etc..

Comment: http://www.prostreams.gg/lol/ that is the site I am trying to implement it on and I am trying to add a script that will check if the stream is live and if so change the color of the twitch icon to say green and red if it is offline.

Comment: I am very new to web dev only been doing it like a week so I am very lost as to how to implement that